# WPF Thread dead lock

Tags: c#, wpf, api, xaml, ef-core-2.0

may i find useful answer from you.
I have WPF application fetching the data from API, I have thread deadlock when i fire following code

```
private List<Clinic> _clinics;
        public List<Clinic> Clinics {
            get { return _clinics; }
            set { _clinics = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private Clinic _selectedClinic;
        public Clinic SelectedClinic {
            get { return _selectedClinic; }
            set {
                _selectedClinic = value; OnPropertyChanged();
                if (value != null)
                    OnSelectClinic(value).Wait();
            }
        }
private async Task OnSelectClinic(Clinic clinic) {
            try {
using (var request = await Client.GetAsync("URL OF API")) {
                if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode){
StaffList = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<Staff>();
}

                var error = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                throw new Exception(error);
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

this is the view model, and Clinics, selectedClinic and Staff are binding to View.XAML

and here is the API Method

```
[HttpGet("FindAllByClinic/{clinicId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> FindAllByClinic(int clinicId) {
            try {
                return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<Staff>>(await _staffRepository
                    .FindAllBy(clinicId)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Here is StaffRepository method :

```
public async Task<ICollection<Staff>> FindAllBy(int clinicId, int medicalPointId) {
            var persons = await Context.Persons.FromSql("EXEC HR.GetPersonsByClinicId @ClinicId = 0," +
                                                        $"@EncryptPassword = '{DecryptPassword}'").ToListAsync();

            var staffs = await Context.Staff
                .Include(e => e.StaffClinics)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.Clinic)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.ClinicMedicalPoints)
                .Where(e => e.StaffClinics.Any(c => c.ClinicId == clinicId
                                                    && c.Clinic.ClinicMedicalPoints.Any(m => m.MedicalPointId
                                                    == medicalPointId)))
                .ToListAsync();

            foreach (var staff in staffs) {
                staff.Person = persons.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == staff.PersonId);
            }

            return staffs;
        }
```

the problem is when i select a clinic from combobox the entire application freeze
Can any one give me suggestions or correct my code if I Have mistakes please

Comment: `OnSelectClinic(value).Wait();` that's the bad guy. Properties are blocking calls anyways (never async), doing anything in them **besides** setting a backing field is wrong and **leads to** issue's like the one you are seeing. See the link ↓

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: you should move `OnSelectClinic` to event rather than on the property set. this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
public Clinic SelectedClinic {
            get { return _selectedClinic; }
            set {
                _selectedClinic = value; OnPropertyChanged();
                if (value != null)
                    OnSelectClinic(value).Wait();
            }
        }
```

This setter is super bad, because:

1. It raises an event with `OnPropertyChanged` - that's okay - but then it continues to perform a costly operation in the setters body. You're already rasing an event, maybe something should subscribe to it and perform the `OnSelectClinic` instead?
2. [You're blocking on `async` code, which is a sin that causes deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Normally the solution is to replace blocking waits with `await`s, but in this case you need to redesign so that a property setter is not responsible for firing and awaiting this operation.

Comment: `It raises an event with OnPropertyChanged` of course this is where you put that, how else do you; **this isn't** *super bad*.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yeah, I don't take issue with that, I take issue with it executing a possibly long-running `async` operation after that - that's not something one would expect a property setter to do, and it's a direct cause of the issue, since it enforces blocking on that operation. Hopefully my edit made it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: So how can i make async call to load staff from API when I Select a Clinic ?

Comment: @MajdAlbaho Move that into a separate event handler that reacts to the `PropertyChangedEvent` raised by this property is the first that comes to mind.

Comment: @V0ldek it works, I used event handler as you say thanks